# Alamofire 5 - Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(multipartFormData:to:usingThreshold:method:headers:interceptor:fileManager:)'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "Image")

        }, to: url, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), method: .post, headers: httpHeaders, interceptor: nil, fileManager: .default)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(multipartFormData:to:usingThreshold:method:headers:interceptor:fileManager:)'"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is actually a problem with one of your parameters. Most often this is due to a type mismatch. Your most likely culprit is the `httpHeaders` value, as Alamofire 5 (which you appear to be using) uses a new `HTTPHeaders` type, rather than `[String: String]`. Updating your headers to use that type may fix the issue.

Additionally, you don't need to pass most of those parameters anyway. Calling just:

```swift
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "Image")
}, to: url, headers: httpHeaders)
```

does the same thing.